# Adobe Acrobat DC highlight text

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I need to highlight texts in several colors but it is only allowing 1 color. How do I change this? I have clicked on it and it doesn't change or offer different colors. It only shows red.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPGVM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color in the property bar. Either press CTRL+E or right click on the icon of the highlight tool and choose "show property bar" (or similar - I don't have the english version).